# 401 with declarative Http Client on the API URL with @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS) annotation

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-client, micronaut-aws

When we add the Micronaut security all the URLs are protected. while using the `@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)` annotation still facing the 401 exception

```
public interface ISubCategoryOperation {
    @Get("/{categoryId}/sub-category")
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
    Maybe<?> get(@NotNull String categoryId);
}
```

The interface method is denoted with `@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)` but still not able to go to the controller method

Http client

```
@Client(id="feteBirdProduct", path = "/category")
public interface ISubCategoryClient extends ISubCategoryOperation{
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller("/category/{categoryId}/sub-category")
public class SubCategoryController implements ISubCategoryOperation {
    @Override
    public Maybe<?> get(@PathVariable String categoryId) {
        return Maybe.Just(null);
    }
```

Curl

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/category/60236833af7a1d49478d2bef/sub-category" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

Http client logs

```
15:17:18.504 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-6] DEBUG i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Sending HTTP GET to http://localhost:8081/category/60236833af7a1d49478d2bef/sub-category
15:17:18.535 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-6] DEBUG i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Received response 401 from http://localhost:8081/category/60236833af7a1d49478d2bef/sub-category
```

Comment: Could you add your application.{yml|properties|json} configuration?

Comment: I think you need to change @Controller("/category/{categoryId}/sub-category") to
@Controller("/category")